# Docker unable to locate package (wkhtmltopdf) while building

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, debian, apt

## EDIT

While troubleshooting I'm getting different errors:

```
...
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
...
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my firewall settings(nftables)
Running
`docker run busybox nslookup google.com`
gives me
`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` so the docker has no connection to the outside?

### Systems

Dev environment: `Ubuntu 22.04`
Prod environment: `debian 10.12 64bit / Linux 4.19.0-20-amd64`

### Dockerfile inside my node backend folder

```
FROM node:slim

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf

RUN npm install -g pm2@latest

WORKDIR /var/api

COPY . .

RUN npm i

EXPOSE 10051-10053

# Start PM2 as PID 1 process
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2-runtime"]
CMD ["process.json"]
```

When building this file on my dev system (Ubuntu 22.04) it works fine.

### However, deploying it go my server and letting it build, I get this output:

```
Building backend
Sending build context to Docker daemon  159.2kB
Step 1/10 : FROM node:slim
 ---> 6c8b32c67190
Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b28ad6ee8ebf
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
 ---> Running in 2f76d2582ac0
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package wkhtmltopdf
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build : Build failed
```

### What I have tried

- Running `apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf` solo on my server installs the package fine.
- Added different repos to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- I know its package https://packages.debian.org/buster/wkhtmltopdf (?)
- Some troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, problem was nftables and docker.
Docker adds iptables rules to the ruleset, all I have to do was this:

> - use an ip and ipv6 table instead of inet
> - name all chains exactly as in iptables: INPUT, OUTPUT & FORWARD

source: https://ehlers.berlin/blog/nftables-and-docker/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run):

> Using apt-get update alone in a RUN statement causes caching issues and subsequent apt-get install instructions fail.

So for your case, you should do:

```bash
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
```

Instead of:

```bash
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Nope unfortunately didn't work, it gave me a different error tho
````
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
```

I guess its something with my dns and nftables config

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing the problem, I downloaded `.deb` and installed it, in my case with `gdebi` but you can also use `dpkg`.

```
RUN echo "### Install wkhtmltopdf ###" \
    && wget -nv -O /tmp/wkhtmltopdf.deb https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb \
    && gdebi --non-interactive /tmp/wkhtmltopdf.deb
```